# Animation from big font to small messes up the positioning

Tags: css, animation

I am currently trying to make an animation with a welcome message. I want it to be placed in the verticalmiddle of my div. I transform it from a big font to a small font and it seems like the big fonts height is still affecting the positioning or am I wrong?

```css
#barbar{
height:10%;
width: 100%;
background-color:rgba(79, 79, 90, 0.92);
bottom: 0;
position: fixed;
z-index: 3;
}

.hello{
    color: black;
    font-family: "Times New Roman";
    text-align: center;
    animation: ease;
    animation-name: gas;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-duration:2s;
    position: fixed;
    font-size: 100px;
    bottom: 700px;
    margin-left: -20%;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
@keyframes gas{
    from { font-size: 500px; bottom: 700px; margin-left: -20%;}
    to  { font-size: 12px; bottom: 0; margin-left: 15%;}
}
```

```html
<div id = "barbar">
  <h3 class ='hello'> Welocme User </h3>
</div>
```

As you can see my `h3` is inside the div but it still somehow doesn't end up where I want it to be placed. `to bottom:-x%` is not the soulution im looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add "margin-bottom: 0;" to your h3 tag.

By default, the browser adds a margin of 1em to h3 elements. Since the "em" unit is relative to font-size, when you add "font-size: 100px" to your element you also get 100px of margin.

I suggest using a CSS reset. It will clear all the browser's defaults, preventing it to add unwanted styles on your page. It also makes sure that your page will look exactly the same in all browsers since different browsers use different defaults. I suggest using [meyerweb reset](https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) on all your pages.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, il look into your suggestion aswell.